# Box Authentication ( Generate Access Token )

Tags: box, boxapiv2

[image]

**Access token generated here last only for 60 minutes , how can i generate token so that it can be used without any time bound.**

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a non-expiring token that I know of whether it's a DEVELOPER_TOKEN, Oauth, or JWT.  Tokens all expire and have to be refreshed.